# Rate youtube video using POST command javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am fairly new to javascript so does anyone know how to do a POST command to like a youtube video?

using this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate
```

with youtube apiv3

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for a LIKE, but first you need to have an authorised user.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=UCXLGzwT-Yw&rating=like&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Video URL/ID = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCXLGzwT-Yw

Good Docs here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

Comment: thanks I have an authorised user, but what would be api key? I have the client Id and the scope

Comment: Would i do something like this when the user clicks on the button?   $("#rateLike").on('click', function (){
  POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=idVid&rating=like&key={API_KEY}     just add the post inside the function when clicked? 

});

Comment: Yes - you will need a jQuery POST request for this. But first you need to get a oauth2 token for the individual user who is performing this rate.

Comment: I have the following post request;  $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id='+idVid+'&rating=like&key={'+API_KEY+'}',function(){}); I also have the individual OAUTH2 token for the user, but where do I include it in the post request?

Comment: $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id='+idVid+'&rating=like&key={'+API_KEY+'}&access_token='+ACCESS_TOKEN,function(){

  });

Answer (score 1):

> $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id='+idVid+'&rating=like&key{'+API_KEY+'}&access_token='+ACCESS_TOKEN,function(){});

This works!